# Trying to make a decision tree

Tags: java, decision-tree

```
Name    Hair    Eyes    Shirt   Glasses Smiling Hat
Alice   BROWN   BLUE    GREEN     YES   YES     NO
Bob     BROWN   BROWN   GREEN     YES   NO     YES
Dave    BROWN   BROWN   GREEN     NO    YES    YES
Emily   BROWN   HAZEL   RED       YES   YES    YES
Frank   BROWN   GREEN   GREEN     YES   YES     NO
Isabelle BROWN  HAZEL   GREEN     YES   YES     NO
Mallie  BROWN   BLUE    RED       YES   YES     NO
Nick    BROWN   BLUE    RED       NO    YES     NO
Philip  BROWN   GREEN   RED       NO    YES     NO
Quinn   BROWN   BROWN   RED       NO    YES     NO
Robert  BROWN   BROWN   RED       NO    YES     YES
Tucker  BROWN   BLUE    BLUE      NO    YES     NO
Wendy   BROWN   BLUE    RED       YES   NO     NO
Zander  BROWN   BROWN   BLUE      NO    YES    NO
```

I have these characters and I was trying to make a decision tree like

```
 if (g.hairIsColor(Color.BROWN)) 
  {
   if(g.isWearingGlasses())
   {
     if(g.shirtIsColor(Color.GREEN))
     {
         k = "Bob";
       if(g.eyeIsColor(Color.GREEN))
       {
       k = "Frank";
       }
       if(g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE))
       {
       k = "Alice";
       break outerloop;
       }
       if(g.eyeIsColor(Color.HAZEL))
       {
       k = "Isabelle";
       }
     }
    if(g.eyeIsColor(Color.HAZEL))
    k = "Emily";
    if (g.isSmiling())
    k = "Mallie";
   }
    else if(g.eyeIsColor(Color.BROWN))
    {
     if (g.shirtIsColor(Color.RED))
     {
       if(g.isWearingHat())
       k = "Robert";
       else 
       k = "Quinn";
     }
     else if(g.shirtIsColor(Color.GREEN))
     k = "Dave";
     else
     k = "Zander";
    }
   else if(g.shirtIsColor(Color.RED))
   { 
    if(g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE))
    k = "Nick";
    if(g.eyeIsColor(Color.GREEN))
    k = "Philip";
   }
  else if(g.eyeIsColor(Color.BLUE) && g.shirtIsColor(Color.BLUE))
  k = "Tucker";
}
```

Unfortunately it took too many tries for each character and was wondering if someone could help me?
I'm trying to get it to 10 or under tries for each character yet I can't seem to get that 50% with if statements
Any help?
I already sorted the other hair colors but brown is giving me trouble

Comment: If you are asking someone to do you homework people won't be willing to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem turns out I started from the wrong first decision and thus ended up doing it wrong. I started with a different if of eye color and proceeded from there and fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it with if-then-else.

1. Create a new class called `Key` to hold the attributes
2. Ensure the class has a valid `hashCode()` and `equals()` method
3. Create a `Map<Key,String>` and initialize it with the contents of the table in your post

When you need to look up somebody, create a new `Key` and set the values of the attributes, using that as the lookup key in the map. As in:

```
Key k = new Key(name, hair, eyes, shirt, glasses, hat, smiling, ...whatever);
String name = map.get(key);
```

Comment: If statements are how i'm supposed to do the project

Comment: Ouch! Doing complex decision trees as series of if-then-else statements is an _anti-pattern_ because they are impossible to understand and maintain.  Just about _any_ alternative approach is better than embedding decision trees in your code.  I'm sorry you are required to do it this way.  I hope the teacher is going to follow up with better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator `if` provides 0 to 1 bit of information:

- `if hair color is brown` provides zero bits because hair color is constant.
- `if glasses` provides one bit because it divides the search space in half.

Using tests that provide a full bit makes it possible *in theory* to identify each person with four tests. Selecting good tests based on the actual data should make it possible to approach this. But it is likely to require each branch of a test to have unique logic. For example `glasses = yes` might test next on shirt color and `glasses = no` might test next on hats in order to divide their respective branches of the search space in half .